# How do I store a struct in two places?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm doing Advent Of Code Day 7 in Rust. I have to parse a tree out of order like so:

```
a(10)
c(5) -> a, b
b(20)
```

That says `c` is the root with `a` and `b` as its children.

I handle this by parsing each line, making an object, and storing it in a hash by name. If it shows up later as a child, like `a`, I can use that hash to lookup the object and apply it as a child. If it shows up as a child before being defined, like `b`, I can create a partial version and update it via the hash.  The above would be something like:

```
let mut np = NodeParser{
    map: HashMap::new(),
    root: None,
};

{
    // This would be the result of parsing "a(10)".
    {
        let a = Node{
            name: "a".to_string(),
            weight: Some(10),
            children: None
        };
        np.map.insert( a.name.clone(), a );
    }

    // This is the result of parsing "c(5) -> a, b".
    // Note that it creates 'b' with incomplete data.
    {
        let b = Node{
            name: "b".to_string(),
            weight: None,
            children: None
        };
        np.map.insert("b".to_string(), b);

        let c = Node{
            name: "c".to_string(),
            weight: Some(5),
            children: Some(vec![
                *np.map.get("a").unwrap(),
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content

                *np.map.get("b").unwrap()
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
            ])
        };
        np.map.insert( c.name.clone(), c );
    }

    // Parsing "b(20)", it's already seen b, so it updates it.
    // This also updates the entry in c.children. It avoids
    // having to search all nodes for any with b as a child.
    {
        let mut b = np.map.get_mut( "b" ).unwrap();
        b.weight = Some(20);
    }
}
```

I might want to look up a node and look at its children.

```
// And if I wanted to look at the children of c...
let node = np.map.get("c").unwrap();
for child in node.children.unwrap() {
//           ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
    println!("{:?}", child);
}
```

Rust does not like this. It doesn't like that both `NodeParser.map` and `Node.children` own a node.

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> /Users/schwern/tmp/test.rs:46:21
   |
46 |                     *np.map.get("a").unwrap(),
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content

error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> /Users/schwern/tmp/test.rs:49:21
   |
49 |                     *np.map.get("b").unwrap()
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

It doesn't like that the `for` loop is trying to borrow the node to iterate because I've already borrowed the node from the `NodeParser` that owns it.

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> /Users/schwern/tmp/test.rs:68:18
   |
68 |     for child in node.children.unwrap() {
   |                  ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

I think I understand what I'm doing wrong, but I'm not sure how to make it right.

How should I construct this to make the borrower happy? Because of the way `NodeParser.map` and `Node.children` must be linked, copying is not an option.

[Here is the code to test with](https://gist.github.com/schwern/6168d8df293360dce9adc9699e6e098e). In the real code both `Node` and `NodeParser` have implementations and methods.

Comment: Instead of directly storing a reference to a node, store them by id (or `name`, in this case) and look them up from `np.map` when needed.

Comment: @EvilTak Thanks for the suggestion. While that would work, I'm looking for something that works with the borrow-checker rather than around it.

Comment: Not sure why you would want that, when an easier solution (except maybe `Rc`s) exists. Why fight the borrow checker (or work with it) when you don't _need_ to? The borrow checker is simply a safety mechanism to prevent references outliving content. You would only want to work with the borrow checker if you _have_ to use borrows.

Comment: @EvilTak Because at some point I will need to store something in two places, it's a common thing in programming, and I won't be able to work around it. I'd rather learn how to do it now while I'm messing around with puzzles than later under time pressure on complicated production code.

Comment: Ah, then the best way is `Rc` or `Arc` combined with a `Cell` if you need mutability.

Answer (score 4):

One option is unsafe code ... but I would suggest avoiding that if you're using the Advent of Code to learn idiomatic Rust and not just drop all the safety its trying to give you.

Another option is to reference count the `Node` instances so that the borrow checker is happy and the compiler knows how to clean things up. The [`std::rc::Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) type does this for you ... and essentially [every call to `clone()` just increments a reference count](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/rc.rs.html#869-872) and returns a new `Rc` instance. Then every time an object is dropped, the `Drop` implementation just decrements the reference count.

As for the iteration .. `for x in y` is syntactic sugar for `for x in y.into_iter()`. This is attempting to move the contents of `children` out of `node` (notice in [the `IntoIterator` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.12.1/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html), `into_iter(self)` takes ownership of `self`). To rectify this, you can ask for a reference instead when iterating, using `for x in &y`. This essentially becomes `for x in y.iter()`, which does not move the contents.

[Here are these suggestions in action](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2d0ac1780c9fb79fc32f69718fa96093&version=stable).

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::rc::Rc;

struct NodeParser {
    map: HashMap<String, Rc<Node>>,
    root: Option<Node>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    name: String,
    children: Option<Vec<Rc<Node>>>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut np = NodeParser{
        map: HashMap::new(),
        root: None,
    };

    let a = Rc::new(Node{ name: "a".to_string(), children: None });
    np.map.insert( a.name.clone(), a.clone() );

    let b = Rc::new(Node{ name: "b".to_string(), children: None });
    np.map.insert( b.name.clone(), b.clone() );

    let c = Rc::new(Node{
        name: "c".to_string(),
        children: Some(vec![a, b])
    });
    np.map.insert( c.name.clone(), c.clone() );

    let node = np.map.get("c").unwrap();
    for child in &node.children {
        println!("{:?}", child);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I will expand on my comment here. [You can use lifetimes here too if you want](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=caed33057205018a8d774c2481320c1f&version=stable), but I'm concerned that the lifetime solution will work against the MCVE and won't work once applied to *the actual problem* the OP (not just of this question... others as well) actually has. Lifetimes are tricky in Rust and small things like re-ordering the instantiation of variables to allow the lifetime solution can throw people off. My concern being they will run into lifetime issues and therefore the answers won't be appropriate to their actual situation even if it works for the MCVE. Maybe I overthink that though..

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated the question to illustrate why copying is not an option, sorry for not having that in the first place. Using `&` on the iteration worked, thank you for the explanation. And yes, I am using AoC to learn idiomatic Rust. Hmm... reference counting would work, but it seems like working around the borrower instead of with it? I'll give it a shot anyway.

Comment: "copying is not an option" - I imagine you're referring to my use of `clone()` in the code? If you re-read my answer I give you an explanation of whats happening behind the scenes here. The only thing that is cloned is the `Rc` instance. Behind the scenes, the `Rc` copies the pointer to what you've wrapped (which will be your child nodes). There is no copying/cloning of the `Node` instances here... just the `Rc` instances. Another thing to be aware of is that "copy" and "clone" individually mean specific things in Rust and confusing the two can often lead to subtle bugs :)

Comment: I get how Rc works. Perl uses reference counting, and I do a lot of Perl. I just wanted to make you aware of the update to the problem as I saw you were actively editing your answer. Could this be solved instead with lifetimes? I'm trying to understand them.

Comment: Sorry about that, my edit was trying to emphasise the new instance of `Rc` versus implying a big clone/copy operation. "Could this be solved instead with lifetimes?" - [well yes, it can if you want](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=caed33057205018a8d774c2481320c1f&version=stable), however it requires restructuring of your code and I often try to avoid that when answering questions because the MCVE's people create generally strip away a lot of the surrounding code. Lifetimes and their use in Rust , require a bit more context around the actual code in use and so applying them can cause confusion

Comment: Yes, that was what I'm looking for, thank you! I'll go make sense of it. [Here's the real code for reference](https://github.com/schwern/adventofcode.rust/tree/324ed2c7b8d0fd642b973bf40a930054789d9739/2017/day07/src). Any comments are appreciated.